# How to read JSON data return by the Facebook access_token

Tags: django, json, facebook-graph-api, django-views

I'm trying to get the facebook username of a logged in user in my site. I have this code in my view (on Django) :

```
code = request.GET.get('code')
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=%(id)s&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/skempi/home&client_secret=%(secret)s&code=%(code)s'%{'id':fb_id,'secret':fb_s,'code':code}
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
dic = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(html))
graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='+dic.get('access_token')
```

when I do `return HttpResponseRedirect(graph_url)` I can see the JSON data. However, I'm not able to read that data using

```
import simplejson
d = simplejson.load(graph_url)
context ={'user':d}
return render_to_response('home.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I get this error :

```
'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually download the JSON before simplejson can decode it.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(graph_url)
data = simplejson.load(response)
```